# Exploring multiple semantic clusters of a given set of terms

Tags: clustering, terminology

I have a list of N object categories(e.g. apple, cell-phone, horse, chair, watch). Are there any methods of obtaining various clusters based on attributes of these categories ? For example, one clustering could be based on natural vs man-made criteria ({apple,horse} , {cell-phone,chair,watch}). Another clustering could be based on shape, appearance etc.

On a related note, are there databases which take this list as input and output attributes of these objects ? For instance, apple has typical attributes: round,red-or-green,fruit.

Comment: Conceptual classification isn't clustering. Clustering is an unsupervised classification, i.e. classification without conceptual "teacher".

Answer (score 0):

Clustering algorithms won't work for this. To them „apple” is a string of 5 characters, but an *unsupervised* algorithm cannot onfer human associations.

You will have to use something like wordnet first. But overall, this is one variation over an unsolved (and in many problem insoluble) problem: humans have a lot of knowledge of the world (e.g.: horses eat apples) that pretty much do not exist in a form easy to process for computers. [NELL](http://rtw.ml.cmu.edu/) is a project aiming at learning such knowledge by reading lots of text. But if you ask NELL about apples, it probably knows there is a company and a fruit; but it won't even know the fruit is often green, usually edible, of that horses would eat one.

Have a look at [apple (plant)](http://rtw.ml.cmu.edu/rtw/kbbrowser/entity.php?id=plant%3Aapple) knowledge of NELL. Apples are controlled by the "job" radiostation (obviously NELL confused that with Steve Jobs...), wozniak and stephen?!? Sorry, looks like I was too optimistic. NELL has learned that apple can be a plant, but it can't yet tell apart whether some text is about the fruit or the company...

You may be overestimating the text analysis capabilities of today - and in fact, language can be really ambiguous and context sensitive.

If at lunchtime you would ask me to cluster your example, I would answer

```
{apple}, {horse, chair, watch, cell-phone}
```

because I eat apples, but not horses. Or maybe

```
{apple, chair}, {horse, watch, cell-phone}
```

because there are apples and chairs in the restaurant, but you can't buy a watch or cell-phone or horse there.

Comment: Perhaps you should replace "unsolved" by "insoluble." This kind of "clustering" is what conceptual categories are formed of. Such categories are by no means unique, universal, or inherent. You might enjoy reading George Lakoff's *Women, Fire, and Dangerous Things.* It begins with an account of how and why a particular Australian aboriginal tribe includes those three kinds of objects within a common category; develops a rich theory of mental concepts to explain how such strange categories can exist; and concludes with case studies applying that theory.

Comment: Of course it will never be perfect. Language is ambiguous, and *very context dependant*. In one setting, a human will understand a sentence very differently than in a different context. And even some hyped efforts like word2vec seem to pick "watch" as the odd one out in "cell-phone horse chair watch", and "chair" as the odd one in "apple cell-phone chair watch"...
In above example, one may argue the clusters should be {apple}, {horse, chair, watch, cell-phone} because I eat apples, but not horses...